# Many issues setting the default gateway on boot-up

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, network-interface, ppp

I am using a BeagleBone embedded computer running Debian.

I have two network interfaces :

1. A connection to a cellular modem over USB which uses ppp and connects to the outside world. It receives a dynamic IP address from the ISP
2. An ethernet interface which is connected only to another local device. I have assigned the static IP address 192.168.1.40 to this interface. I set this inside rc.local with command `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.40 netmask 255.255.255.0`

Only when the two interfaces are active, there is a problem to connect out through the modem. I realized that to solve this I have to set the default gateway to the address that the modem gets by running a script with my below commands.

```
#!/bin/sh
IPADD=&(/sbin/ifconfig ppp0 | grep 'inet' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $2}')
route add default gw $IPADD
```

This works great when I manually execute my script after login. I can then communicate out through the two interfaces.

However, I am not able whatsoever to get this script to execute on boot-up properly and assign the the default gateway address automatically this way.

I have tried everything, by running it from rc.local, putting the script in /etc/rc5.d or /etc/rc3.d, running it from /root/.bashrc or /user/.bashrc. Using crontab, trying to sleep 1 minute before running the script, running it in a loop. Nothing works.

It seems after I login, the default gateway gets overwritten somehow from having the ethernet interface.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? I need this default gateway address to be assigned on boot-up automatically. I've been trying for days now.

If I don't have the ethernet cable plugged in , or I put the ethernet interface down, there are no problems at all. Only with the two interfaces active I have this problem.

Comment: Which version of Debian are you using? What network management software do you have installed and running after you login (including ifupdown, NetworkManager, networkd, DHCP clients)? Have you tried adding the default route as a device route via ppp0 without a gateway address? (It's a point-to-point device anyway.)

Comment: @grawity It's the latest version of Debian for the BeagleBone. I'm not sure about the network management software. How would I add the default route as a device route via ppp0 without a gw address? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: If the external interface is always the same you could check whenever you can use the interface name rather than the IP for the route.

Comment: @Seth I don't understand sorry

Comment: Using iproute2, `ip route add default via $IPADD` is the regular version with a gateway, `ip route add default dev ppp0` is the device-only version. Simplifies your script a bit. (Point-to-point interfaces don't have a MAC layer, so the gateway address isn't actually _used_ for anything anyway.)

Comment: @grawity There are errors when I use those commands. "RTNETLINK answers : File exists"   . It only works when I use "route add default gw $IPADD"